# download qr code canvas as image with background

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am in trouble trying to download QR code canvas as image with background.
Download works fine but my device cannot scanner the code due to un-complete border. I need to make white background behind larger.

Current image:
[image: Current downloaded image:]

Expect image:
[image: Expect image:]

My current code:

```
<a id="download-qr">
<div id="qrCode"></div>
```

```
  $('#qrCode').qrcode({
     render: "canvas",
     minVersion: 8,
     maxVersion: 8,
     ecLevel: 'M',
     size: 200,
     mode: 0,
     text: code,
  });

  var canvas = $("#qrCode").children(":first")[0];
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
  var dl = document.getElementById('download-qr');
  dl.setAttribute('href', img);
  dl.setAttribute('download', 'test.jpg');
```

Please help me. Thanks so much.

Comment: Add your `test (30).jpg` to some file exchange servers. It seems to me, that file is OK, but your image preview app is adding black background all the time.

Comment: What api / library are you using, you need to specify that in the post

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add white border to you ctx object.

```
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: I have tried but it does not work. Nothing changes :(

Comment: That wouldnt work unless you resized the canvas.

From what I can tell, it seems the canvas is actually the size of the QR code

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need yours method of generating QR code... if not, you can use [Qurious](https://github.com/neocotic/qrious) which has a its own padding option - it also generates qr code in canvas.

Add this at the head part:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qrious/4.0.2/qrious.min.js"></script>
```

Html:

```
<canvas id="qrCode"></canvas>
```

Script:

```
const makeQR = (your_value) => {
      let qrcodeContainer = document.getElementById("qrCode");
        qrcodeContainer.innerHTML = "";
        new QRious({
          element: qrcodeContainer,
          value: your_value,
          size: 600,
          padding:50,
        }); // generate QR code
        
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.download = 'your_file.png';
        link.href = document.getElementById('qrCode').toDataURL()
        link.click(); // download it
        
    }

makeQR("your value")
```